# String not showing up in output

Tags: java, error-handling, syntax-error

There is no compilation error, however the input string is not showing up. There's just a blank in its place. Am I missing something?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d=scan.nextDouble();
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem combing Scanner#next*() methods with Scanner#nextLine(). I never use Scanner, but rather I take input from a BufferedReader initialized on System.in.

Comment: @NomadMaker just get used to always initializing your scanner properly: `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R")`, and then just call `.next()` for a line, `.nextInt()` for an int, etc.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I've been programming Java since the first beta, and I've never used Scanner. BufferedReader#readLine() has been my favorite when I'm slumming in the console rather than using a gui.

Comment: @NomadMaker When I started my programming career, it was with QBasic. I don't use that anymore, though :)